# How can we control "SignUpSignInPolicyId" in authentication scheme

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-application-options

How can we control "SignUpSignInPolicyId" in authentication scheme.

Requirement -
If we click one button then it should redirect us to one sign up sign in policy. and if we click on another button on application then it should take us to another sign up sign in policy. Basically we want to control SignUpSignInPolicyId for different sign in option.

I have my own controller for sign in.

Can any one suggest how can we customize this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can  control "SignUpSignInPolicyId" in authentication scheme by
finding the key `SignUpSignInPolicyId` and replace with the name of the `Sign up and sign in` policy you created at  your local IDE (VS or VS CODE).

For further information please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/how-to-secure-a-web-api-built-with-aspnet-core-using-the-azure-ad-b2c/).& [git-hub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/tests/B2CWebAppCallsWebApi/README.md) issue.